# How to make valid route for {id}/visit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I am new at asp.core , so I try to make valid route to `{id}/visits`

My code:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("/Users")]
public class UserController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}/visits")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] long id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException()
    }
}
```

But, at route `{id}` generated method the same:

```
// GET: /Users/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] long id)
{
    return Ok(user);
}
```

How to make route `/Users/5/visits` nethod?
What parameters at `GetUser` should I add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name the methods differently and use constraints to avoid route conflicts:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[RoutePrefix("Users")] // different attribute here and not starting /slash
public class UserController 
{
    // Gets a specific user
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:long}")] // Matches GET Users/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] long id)
    {
        // do what needs to be done
    }

    // Gets all visits from a specific user
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:long}/visits")] // Matches GET Users/5/visits
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserVisits([FromRoute] long id) // method name different
    {
        // do what needs to be done
    }
}
```